# Apply family of functions for functions with multiple arguments

Tags: r, apply

I would like to use a function from the apply family (in R) to apply a function of two arguments to two matrices.  I assume this is possible.  Am I correct?  Otherwise, it would seem that I have to put the two matrices into one, and redefine my function in terms of the new matrix.

Here's an example of what I'd like to do:

```
a <- matrix(1:6,nrow = 3,ncol = 2)
b <- matrix(7:12,nrow = 3,ncol = 2)

foo <- function(vec1,vec2){
    d <- sample(vec1,1)
    f <- sample(vec2,1)
    result <- c(d,f)
return(result)
}
```

I would like to apply `foo` to `a` and `b`.

Comment: Please tag your question with what language you are using.

Comment: Oops, thanks for the reminder.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want your function to do and how you're connected your matrices to the inputs to the function.  Are you just saying you want to get a single sample from each row of each matrix?  Why do you need to do this simultaneously for both matrices?

Comment: Or do you want a sample from each column?  Please update your question to make it more clear what you're actually hoping for.

Comment: You bring up a good point. I could definitely just make this a function of one argument, and perform the desired operations separately, and combine them like I do in `result`.  For my practical purposes, this is will be sufficient.  However, I'm trying to become more proficient with the apply family, so I'm still interested in a solution for the question I posed.

Comment: Then please update with more details on what you're actually doing.  Like I said it's not clear to me from your problem description what you actually want done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Strictly answering the question, not pointing you to a better approach for you particular use here....)

`mapply` is the function from the `*apply` family of functions for applying a function while looping through multiple arguments.

So what you want to do here is turn each of your matrices into a list of vectors that hold its rows or columns (you did not specify). There are many ways to do that, I like to use the following function:

```
split.array.along <- function(X, MARGIN) {
    require(abind)
    lapply(seq_len(dim(X)[MARGIN]), asub, x = X, dims = MARGIN)
}
```

Then all you have to do is run:

```
mapply(foo, split.array.along(a, 1),
            split.array.along(b, 1))
```

Like `sapply`, `mapply` tries to put your output into an array if possible. If instead you prefer the output to be a list, add `SIMPLIFY = FALSE` to the `mapply` call, or equivalently, use the `Map function:`

```
Map(foo, split.array.along(a, 1),
         split.array.along(b, 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could adjust `foo` to take one argument (a single matrix), and use `apply` in the function body.
Then you can use `lapply` on `foo` to sample from each column of each matrix.

```
> a <- matrix(1:6,nrow = 3,ncol = 2)
> b <- matrix(7:12,nrow = 3,ncol = 2)

> foo <- function(x){
    apply(x, 2, function(z) sample(z, 1))
  }

> lapply(list(a, b), foo)

## [[1]]
## [1] 1 6

## [[2]]
## [1]  8 12
```