# Iterative approach code in R to make more efficient?

Tags: r, for-loop

I am using Merton default model with complex iterative approach.

I have already prepared my **R** codes but as I am quite new in **R**, they seem very inefficient, in sense that they runs almost 7 hours. My main problem is my for loop part.

I kindly ask you review my **R** code and give any corrections which could make my **R** code more efficient i.e. they run less time
I downloaded all data and **R** code here:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/jlqvao40e5nvkev/AACpPdAdG67juhX9HoHPpiC1a

**EDIT:**
The below loop runs a lot, maybe you know some function which I can replace with while and for loop here, I suppose sappy can work but I do not know how to apply it:

```
  errors<-ddply( df5, .(id, BSheetyearlag), function(x) sum((x$iterK-x$iterK1)^2))

  df5<-as.data.frame(df5)
  df5<-join(df5, errors, by=c("id", "BSheetyearlag"))
  df5<-as.data.table(df5)
  for ( i in 1:nrow(errors)){
  while(errors$V1[i] >= 10^(-10)) {
  df5<-as.data.table(df5)
  df5[,iterK:= iterK1,by=c("id", "BSheetyearlag")] 
  df5[,assetreturn:=c(NA,diff(log(iterK))),by=c("id", "BSheetyearlag")] 
  df5[,rollsdasset:=rollapply(assetreturn, 249, sd, fill=NA, align='right')*sqrt(250), by=c("id", "BSheetyearlag")]
  df5[,iterK1:=(cap+LTD05*exp(-rfabsol)*pnorm(blackscholes(iterK,LTD05,rfabsol, 1,rollsdasset[250]))-rollsdasset[250])/pnorm(blackscholes(iterK,LTD05,rfabsol, 1,rollsdasset[250])),by=c("id", "BSheetyearlag")]
  df5<-as.data.frame(df5)
  errors$V1[i]<-sum((df5[df5$V1 %in% errors$V1[i],"iterK"]-df5[df5$V1 %in% errors$V1[i],"iterK1"])^2)
        }
        }
```

Comment: This site is for specific questions.

Comment: My question in for loop part , but for overall understanding I downloaded all data

Comment: Do not use a dropbox location to show the problem.  Reduce the size of the problem to the point where you can enter the code and the data into the question itself.  As it is, this question is not a good fit for SO.

Comment: Suggest you move this to: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I am sorry that I put my question not in clear way. I will try to present in a good format.

Comment: That is not reproducible by others.  The `library()` statements and the test code and inputs to run it are missing.

Answer (score 2):

In general, R provides a host of functions that perform loops. They are called the `apply` family of functions. For specific syntax and details, in the R console type:

```
?apply
```

In addition, here are some links to help you get familiar with these functions.

- [Overview](http://people.stern.nyu.edu/ylin/r_apply_family.html)
- [An SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22430585/apply-family-of-functions-for-functions-with-multiple-arguments)
- [YouTube video from Google
  Developers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WuCVs3bW-ZY)

Also, since you are new to R, you should look into the debugging tools that ship with base R.

```
traceback() 
# - prints out the function call stack after an error occurs
# - does nothing if there's no error
# - only gives the most recent error- call right away

recover()   
# allows you to modify the error behavior so that you can
# browse the function call stack

debug()
# flags a function for "debug" mode which allows you to step
# through execution of a function one line at a time.

browser()
# suspends the execuction of a function wherever it is
# called and puts the function in debug mode.
# You can put this anywhere in the code and it will start there.

trace()
# allows you to insert debugging code into a function in
# in specific places
```

There is also R Profiler which can be accessed via `Rprof()`. Check out it's documentation with `?Rprof`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for precious suggestions +1

Comment: My pleasure. In the future, try to be specific about a bottleneck or an error. Now that you have the tools to do just that, I have high hopes you'll get it running.